# ImportError on mayavi.mlab function

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, mayavi

i just started a graphics lecture and wanted to play around with python2.7 since we will need this for our lecture.

We were instructed to install the miniconda distribution from https://conda.io/miniconda.html
and then install further libraries using conda

now ive got the following imports:

```
import math
import numpy  as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import pickle
```

and this funcion:

```
def trimesh(F, V, new_figure=True):
    x = V[:,0]
    y = V[:,1]
    z = V[:,2]
    mlab.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, F)
    if new_figure:
        mlab.figure()
```

as for now it seems that the line `mlab.triangular_mesh()` is giving me an issue.

I get the following error in my PyCharm console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/PycharmProjects/untitled/transformation.py", line 50, in <module>
    trimesh(F, V)
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/PycharmProjects/untitled/transformation.py", line 26, in trimesh
    mlab.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, F)
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/helper_functions.py", line 37, in the_function
    return pipeline(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/helper_functions.py", line 77, in __call__
    scene = tools.gcf().scene
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/figure.py", line 113, in gcf
    engine = get_engine()
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/engine_manager.py", line 101, in get_engine
    return self.new_engine()
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/engine_manager.py", line 146, in new_engine
    check_backend()
  File "/Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/engine_manager.py", line 49, in check_backend
    ''')
ImportError: Could not import backend for traits
_______________________________________________________________________________
Make sure that you have either the TraitsBackendWx or the TraitsBackendQt
projects installed. If you installed Mayavi with easy_install, try
easy_install <pkg_name>. easy_install Mayavi[app] will also work.

If you performed a source checkout, be sure to run 'python setup.py install'
in Traits, TraitsGUI, and the Traits backend of your choice.

Also make sure that either wxPython or PyQT is installed.
wxPython: http://www.wxpython.org/
PyQT: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Im Using python2.7 on macOS 10.13
Here is my conda.info output:

```
Current conda install:

               platform : osx-64
          conda version : 4.3.30
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.30
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 2.7.13.final.0
       requests version : 2.14.2
       root environment : /Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2  (writable)
    default environment : /Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2
       envs directories : /Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/envs
                          /Users/ronaldbrenner/.conda/envs
          package cache : /Users/ronaldbrenner/miniconda2/pkgs
                          /Users/ronaldbrenner/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.14.2 CPython/2.7.13 Darwin/17.0.0 OSX/10.13    
                UID:GID : 501:20
```

I hope someone can help me on this one since im not very experienced with python. Or did someone run into similar problems?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Ronald

Comment: it says you need wxpython or pyqt installed (or pyside, I assume). Do you have any of those installed?

Comment: Hi Corley Brigman. Thanks for your comment.
Using `conda list` i see those installed (with many more):
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py27_4  
pyside                    1.1.1                    py27_0

Comment: I remember having a similar problem on linux, and I only remember looking at [this issue](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/483) before the problem went away. So in my case I think I had to install pyqt4, but that seems to be available for you. Perhaps the newer pyside version mentioned in the last comment?

Comment: ok something happened there after installing the newer pyside version my former error went away. Now i get this error many times:

`ERROR: In /Users/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/VTK-6.3.0/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkOpenGLPainterDeviceAdapter.cxx, line 337
vtkOpenGLPainterDeviceAdapter (0x7fe076ed5e00): Unsupported type for vertices: 8`

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like an improvement in a sense: that seems to come from vtk itself, the hard-core framework that is used by mayavi to do the heavy lifting. Was vtk installed via conda? I don't know whether it matters that your vtk version 6.3.0 is two releases behind the current newest.

Comment: i installed vtk via conda and after calling `conda update vtk` it remains at version 6.3.0
Is there another way to update it?
Could be another problem, that i call this method with wrong arguments?
```
mlab.triangular_mesh(x, y, z, F)
````

Comment: Well if you want to make sure that mayavi works in general, try just `from mayavi import mlab; mlab.test_contour3d()`. I expect the same or a similar error to arise (if it works, we can start debugging your code). I needed vtk for python 3, so I compiled 8.0 myself. Admittedly a tedious process, but then it all worked fine for me. Hopefully others closer to your experience can help.

Comment: if i run this code
`from mayavi import mlab`
`mlab.test_contour3d()`
it finishes successful with exit code 0

Comment: You might need `mlab.show()` afterwards to make the window pop up. But if it doesn't throw an error it's probably working. In that case put together a small dummy example with random or hard-wired inputs of a given shape (mimicking your actual problem) and see where it goes wrong. And note that if you don't explicitly [notify me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) I won't see if you respond.